# Filling between a curve and a Line

Tags: graphics, filling

How do I fill the space between a `Cos` curve and a horizontal `Line` Linking to points on the curve? Say, I would like fill the space between a `Line[{{Pi/4, Cos[Pi/4]}, {-Pi/4, Cos[Pi/4]}}]` the curve `Cos[x]`, `{x, -Pi/4, Pi/4}`.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html ?

Answer (score 4):

Your `Line` has a constant $y$ value... so I picked a bit more adventurous example:

```
With[{line =
   Interpolation[
     {{-Pi, Cos[-Pi]}, {Pi/4, Cos[Pi/4]}},
     InterpolationOrder -> 1]},
 Plot[{Cos[x], Quiet[line[x]]}, {x, -Pi, Pi/4}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]]
```

[image]

Line coordinates are fed to first-order `Interpolation` which creates a function corresponding its $y$ value. This is used as the second equation on `Plot`. With `Filling` one can specify the interval to fill (and with `FillingStyle` one can modify the appearance).

(`Quiet` is used to silence possible warnings on extrapolation of the resulting `InterpolationFunction`.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Plot[{Cos[x], Cos[\[Pi]/4]}, {x, -\[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!